# No results querying lists sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

When querying list through the sharepont rest api with a certain site I seem to be getting no results with a successful response back though the same query with another sharepoint site seems to return results back fine.

For the oauth I'm setting AllSites.Manage and multi-tenant in Azure Portal. Are there any site specific permissions that I need to enable that may be preventing any results from being returned.

```
import requests

url = "https://blah.sharepoint.com/subsite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle%28%27Documents%27%29/Items"

querystring = {"$top":"100"}

headers = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer blahToken"    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I should be getting back the all the documents in this list but instead I get a successful XML response but with no content.

Comment: check document(s) permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the documents in document library having unique permissions (not inheriting from document library) and the account used to query doesnt have permissions to view those documents?